# Question about inequalities between consecutive primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Can any two consecutive primes $p_n$ and $p_{n+1}$ satisfy the inequality $3p_n+1<2p_{n+1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia page for Bertrand's Postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Better_results):

> Jitsuro Nagura proved that for $n \geq 25$, there is always a prime between $n$ and $\left(1+\frac{1}{5}\right)n$.

That should be easy to translate to proving there must be a prime between $p_n$ and $\frac{3}{2}p_n$, with some special cases for $p_n<25$, thus showing that there is no solution to your inequality.